# Running ASP.NET Core Angular template on Kestrel server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to run the ASP.NET Core angular template on a kestrel server. It works flawlessly on ASP.NET, but when I change in the launchsettings in Visual Studio from IIS Express to my project name, it opens a command window where I can see the log and everything, but the browser returns a 404 error. This is what my launchsettings look like:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59994/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Sankini": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Production": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress"
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to make sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

You will want the IISExpress server to serve your Angular App.

The NameOfEnvironmentWhenAppRuns is the name you assign the run button. Like so.

[image]

[image]

So to answer your question the following will work.

```
    "Sankini": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
```